# Mac safari set Interval pause when tab is in background

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using setInterval & setTimeout both tried in our demo for a time interval. When on safari we will minimize the screen these two methods pause and not working. so, we will get a value mismatch in windows chrome and mac safari.

Anyone can help with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome will suspend or slow down timers in some situations as well, I'd be surprised if Firefox doesn't. You can't control how the browser de-prioritizes your window/tab when it's not active.

It's never a good idea to rely on the timer interval, whether `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Any number of things can delay the timer callback, making it happen later than you asked.

If the exact amount of time that passed is important, remember when you started the timer (`const start = Date.now();`) and find out how long it's **really** been when the timer callback is called (`const elapsed = Date.now() - start;`) and act accordingly.

Comment: yeah, I have been tried that and fixed the issue. thanks a lot for a great help